# Mocking of a list

Tags: java, junit, mockito

can we a create a mock variable for a list
@Mock
private ArrayList  user;

If i do this im getting a null pointer exceptions. Which one is better approach using a mock for  list of an object like above  or mock objects added to a list ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mockito ArrayList<String> problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922320/mockito-arrayliststring-problem)

Comment: I recommend not to use mock collection objects like ArrayList. IMHO there is no value in mocking such simple classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using forEach loop to iterate arrayList? it returns iterator back that you haven't mocked. Its better to mock objects of an arraylist because then you can iterate using forEach

Comment: Bingo. Tends to be a real pain in the... behind to correctly mock a list. Much more code than it's worth, so using an ArrayList or extending it is often the better choice.

Comment: well, im iterating using for each loop, but instead of returning iterator its returning  null

Comment: Yes becasue by default mock returns null for every method that return something.

Comment: we get null for only when we mock collections right? not in the case of mocking a class  like  @mock private User user;